# Do I need to fill this void before flashing over it, and what product should I use?

Tags: repair, wood, siding, flashing

I'm putting on a new porch for my parents, and I've got a good handle on a build plan, but one aspect I've never really done before is flashing. For the most part it seems straightforward, but there's one area I'm not sure on. Here's a pic:

[image]

There's a void there, for sure. The wood doesn't seem to be rotting and the area is under the eaves, so there's not a ton of water getting back there if there's any. I think I know how I'm going to flash over it, but I'm wondering if/how I should fill that void first. Wood putty? Some sort of spray product?

Homeowners are clear that they don't want to start ripping off siding and replacing sheathing and that sort of thing. As I said, the majority of the house wood is rock solid, and even this part doesn't seem too bad to the touch. I'd just like to seal it up as well as possible before I put a new deck on it for them.

Anyone have a product I could use to do that, or a tip or trick I might try?

Comment: "this part doesn't seem too bad to the touch" Is this area soft like its started to rot or is there just material missing? If it's rot, you'll do your folks a favor long-term by fixing it properly instead of letting them bury their heads in the sand and pretend it's not a problem.